# How to seperate single list into multiple list in python?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, numpy

I don't know much about python. If I have list looks like the below,

```
asign=[
[['2013-11-14', 52, None, None], ['2013-11-15', 74, None, None], ['2013-11-16', 189, None, None],['2013-11-17', 27, None, None], ['2013-11-18', 11, None, None], ['2013-11-19', 14, None, None],['2013-11-20', 0, None, None]],
[['2013-11-14', 129, None, None], ['2013-11-15', 113, None, None],['2013-11-16', 58, None, None], ['2013-11-17', 34, None, None], ['2013-11-18', 14, None, None],['2013-11-19', 13, None, None], ['2013-11-20', 0, None, None]],
[['2013-11-14', 56, None, None],['2013-11-15', 75, None, None], ['2013-11-16', 29, None, None], ['2013-11-17', 156, None, None],['2013-11-18', 46, None, None], ['2013-11-19', 85, None, None], ['2013-11-20', 6, None, None]],
[['2013-11-14', 111, None, None], ['2013-11-15', 227, None, None], ['2013-11-16', 166, None, None],['2013-11-17', 145, None, None], ['2013-11-18', 23, None, None], ['2013-11-19', 36, None, None],['2013-11-20', 1, None, None]], 
[['2013-11-14', 22, None, None], ['2013-11-15', 20, None, None],['2013-11-16', 13, None, None],['2013-11-17', 12, None, None], ['2013-11-18', 10, None, None],['2013-11-19', 2, None, None], ['2013-11-20', 6, None, None]], 
[['2013-11-14', 33, None, None],['2013-11-15', 28, None, None], ['2013-11-16', 35, None, None], ['2013-11-17', 14, None, None],['2013-11-18', 14, None, None], ['2013-11-19', 6, None, None], ['2013-11-20', 1, None, None]],
[['2013-11-14', 28, None, None], ['2013-11-15', 35, None, None], ['2013-11-16', 20, None, None],
['2013-11-17', 7, None, None], ['2013-11-18', 15, None, None], ['2013-11-19', 14, None, None],
['2013-11-20', 0, None, None]]  
]
```

How can I convert this list to be like the list below?

```
[
['2013-11-14', 52, None, None, 129, None, None, 56, None, None, 111, None, None,
 22, None, None, 33, None, None, 28, None, None],
['2013-11-15', 74, None, None, 113, None, None, 75, None, None, 227, None, None, 20, None, None, 28, None, None,35, None, None],
['2013-11-16', 189, None, None, 58, None, None, 29, None, None,166, None, None, 13, None, None, 35, None, None, 20, None, None],
['2013-11-17', 27, None, None, 34, None, None, 156, None, None, 145, None, None, 12, None, None,14, None, None, 7, None, None],
['2013-11-18', 11, None, None, 14, None, None, 46, None, None, 23, None, None, 10, None, None, 14, None, None, 15, None, None],
['2013-11-19', 14, None, None, 13, None, None, 85, None, None, 36, None, None, 2, N
one, None, 6, None, None, 14, None, None],
['2013-11-20', 0, None, None, 0, None,None, 6, None, None, 1, None, None, 6, None, None, 1, None, None, 0, None, None]
]
```

Please help me, thank you!

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you want to do, in words? It's hard to decipher your intent from a giant wall of unintelligible data.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want the final result in a dictionary, with the value as grouped lists?

Comment: The asign[0][0][0] contains date, i want to seperate the array according to the date.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest this sounds like a homework problem to me, but that's just me. I do not agree with doing someone else's homework, however I will help you with what I would do. I would separate each list out of the main list. Then, I would do a for loop with an if statement to sort them out. Remember if you were to do this to quote the item you are looking for. After the if statement, have it append to a new list. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

By using `numpy`,

```
import numpy as np
data = np.array(asign)

np.hstack((data[0], data[1, :, 1:], data[2, :, 1:],
          data[3, :, 1:], data[4, :, 1:], data[5, :, 1:],
          data[6, :, 1:]))
```

Please consider to use loop to build proper tuple argument for `hstack`

Comment: +1, you can use loop like this - `np.hstack([data[0]] + [data[i,:,1:] for i in range(1, len(data))])`

Answer (score 0):

I would rather go for a dictionary approach. As for a tutorial on python, I would recommend http://www.afterhoursprogramming.com/tutorial/Python/Overview/

```
asign=[
[['2013-11-14', 52, None, None], ['2013-11-15', 74, None, None], ['2013-11-16', 189, None, None],['2013-11-17', 27, None, None], ['2013-11-18', 11, None, None], ['2013-11-19', 14, None, None],['2013-11-20', 0, None, None]],
[['2013-11-14', 129, None, None], ['2013-11-15', 113, None, None],['2013-11-16', 58, None, None], ['2013-11-17', 34, None, None], ['2013-11-18', 14, None, None],['2013-11-19', 13, None, None], ['2013-11-20', 0, None, None]],
[['2013-11-14', 56, None, None], ['2013-11-15', 75, None, None], ['2013-11-16', 29, None, None], ['2013-11-17', 156, None, None], ['2013-11-18', 46, None, None], ['2013-11-19', 85, None, None], ['2013-11-20', 6, None, None]],
[['2013-11-14', 111, None, None], ['2013-11-15', 227, None, None], ['2013-11-16', 166, None, None],['2013-11-17', 145, None, None], ['2013-11-18', 23, None, None], ['2013-11-19', 36, None, None],['2013-11-20', 1, None, None]],
[['2013-11-14', 22, None, None], ['2013-11-15', 20, None, None],['2013-11-16', 13, None, None],['2013-11-17', 12, None, None], ['2013-11-18', 10, None, None],['2013-11-19', 2, None, None], ['2013-11-20', 6, None, None]],
[['2013-11-14', 33, None, None], ['2013-11-15', 28, None, None], ['2013-11-16', 35, None, None], ['2013-11-17', 14, None, None],['2013-11-18', 14, None, None], ['2013-11-19', 6, None, None], ['2013-11-20', 1, None, None]],
[['2013-11-14', 28, None, None], ['2013-11-15', 35, None, None], ['2013-11-16', 20, None, None], ['2013-11-17', 7, None, None], ['2013-11-18', 15, None, None], ['2013-11-19', 14, None, None], ['2013-11-20', 0, None, None]]
]
asign_dict = {}
for data in asign:
    for more_data in data:
        if more_data[0] in asign_dict:
            asign_dict[more_data[0]].extend(more_data[1:])
        else:
            asign_dict[more_data[0]] = more_data[1:]

print asign_dict
```

Corresponding output

```
{
 '2013-11-14': [52, None, None, 129, None, None, 56, None, None, 111, None, None, 22, None, None, 33, None, None, 28, None, None],
 '2013-11-15': [74, None, None, 113, None, None, 75, None, None, 227, None, None, 20, None, None, 28, None, None, 35, None, None],
 '2013-11-16': [189, None, None, 58, None, None, 29, None, None, 166, None, None, 13, None, None, 35, None, None, 20, None, None],
 '2013-11-17': [27, None, None, 34, None, None, 156, None, None, 145, None, None, 12, None, None, 14, None, None, 7, None, None],
 '2013-11-18': [11, None, None, 14, None, None, 46, None, None, 23, None, None, 10, None, None, 14, None, None, 15, None, None],
 '2013-11-19': [14, None, None, 13, None, None, 85, None, None, 36, None, None, 2, None, None, 6, None, None, 14, None, None],
 '2013-11-20': [0, None, None, 0, None, None, 6, None, None, 1, None, None, 6, None, None, 1, None, None, 0, None, None]
}
```

Comment: I can convert the asign_dict into list of format what ever i have mentioned above right??

Comment: You'll need to do something like `[[key]+value for key, value in asign_dict.items()]` to get a list.

Answer (score 0):

This seems a job for Numpy but I do not know enough. With standard library my solution is not much different from Ashish Nitin Patil answer:

```
def add(obj):
    head = obj[0]
    if head in heads:
        result[heads.index(head)].extend(obj[1:])
    else:
        heads.append(head)
        result.append(obj)

result, heads = [], []
unique = [obj for level1 in asign for obj in level1]
map(add, unique)
print result
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    asign = asign=[
[['2013-11-14', 52, None, None], ['2013-11-15', 74, None, None], ['2013-11-16', 189, None, None],['2013-11-17', 27, None, None], ['2013-11-18', 11, None, None], ['2013-11-19', 14, None, None],['2013-11-20', 0, None, None]],
[['2013-11-14', 129, None, None], ['2013-11-15', 113, None, None],['2013-11-16', 58, None, None], ['2013-11-17', 34, None, None], ['2013-11-18', 14, None, None],['2013-11-19', 13, None, None], ['2013-11-20', 0, None, None]],
[['2013-11-14', 56, None, None],['2013-11-15', 75, None, None], ['2013-11-16', 29, None, None], ['2013-11-17', 156, None, None],['2013-11-18', 46, None, None], ['2013-11-19', 85, None, None], ['2013-11-20', 6, None, None]],
[['2013-11-14', 111, None, None], ['2013-11-15', 227, None, None], ['2013-11-16', 166, None, None],['2013-11-17', 145, None, None], ['2013-11-18', 23, None, None], ['2013-11-19', 36, None, None],['2013-11-20', 1, None, None]], 
[['2013-11-14', 22, None, None], ['2013-11-15', 20, None, None],['2013-11-16', 13, None, None]['2013-11-17', 12, None, None], ['2013-11-18', 10, None, None],['2013-11-19', 2, None, None], ['2013-11-20', 6, None, None]], 
[['2013-11-14', 33, None, None],['2013-11-15', 28, None, None], ['2013-11-16', 35, None, None], ['2013-11-17', 14, None, None],['2013-11-18', 14, None, None], ['2013-11-19', 6, None, None], ['2013-11-20', 1, None, None]],
[['2013-11-14', 28, None, None], ['2013-11-15', 35, None, None], ['2013-11-16', 20, None, None],
['2013-11-17', 7, None, None], ['2013-11-18', 15, None, None], ['2013-11-19', 14, None, None],
['2013-11-20', 0, None, None]]  
]
    mydata = []
        for i in range(0,6):
            data = []
            for each in asign:
                if each[i][0] not in data:
                    data.append(each[i][0])
                del each[i][0]
                data.extend(each[i])
            mydata.append(data)
        print mydata
```